# Update the youtube video's title in a popup window of my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

Every time I switch videos on youtube, the title doesn't change in my popup window. I have to manually refresh the page for the title to change. Which script should take care of doing this ? Any help is really appreciated. I'm using javascript for the first time.

```
<!-- popup.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>YouTube Song Matcher Popup</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>YouTube Song Matcher</h1>

<div id="songInfo">
  <h2>Currently Playing:</h2>
  <p id="videoTitle"></p>
</div>

<div id="matchingSongs">
  <h2>Matching Songs:</h2>
  <ul id="songList"></ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
// Popup script (popup.js)

// Retrieve the stored video title from localStorage
function getStoredVideoTitle() {
    return localStorage.getItem('videoTitle') || '';
}

// Set the video title in localStorage
function setVideoTitle(videoTitle) {
    localStorage.setItem('videoTitle', videoTitle);
}

// Function to display the video title in the popup window
function displayVideoTitle(videoTitle) {
    document.getElementById('videoTitle').textContent = videoTitle;
}

// Retrieve the stored video title and display it in the popup when loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    displayVideoTitle(getStoredVideoTitle());
});

// Message listener for receiving the video title from the background script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.type === 'VIDEO_TITLE') {
        const videoTitle = message.title;
        // Store the video title in localStorage for persistence
        setVideoTitle(videoTitle);
        // Display the video title in the popup window
        displayVideoTitle(videoTitle);
    }
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` only happens once, when the DOM content is loaded.

Comment: Show your content script and manifest.json.